# Function Misbehaving When Passed Down as Prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a `PaymentWidgetFooter` component with three buttons.

```
const PaymentWidgetFooter = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return(
        <div ref={ref}>
            <button className={`...`} onClick={() => props.setActiveView(1)} />
            <button className={`...`} onClick={() => props.setActiveView(2)} />
            <button className={`...`} onClick={() => props.setActiveView(3)} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Its props consist of a `setActiveView()` function that the component calls and supplies with a number between 1-3 (inclusive) as a parameter.

```
<NewPaymentWidgetFooter ref={footerRef} setActiveView={() => setActiveView()} />
```

Once this happens, a `useEffect` hook notices the change in the state variable of the parent component and triggers a `updateSubviewStyles()` function which updates a dictionary that is supplied to other views to set their absolute position.

```
useEffect(() => {
        updateSubviewStyles()
    }, [activeView])

function updateSubviewStyles() {
    setSubviewStyle(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        1: {
            ...prevState[1],
            left: (1 - activeView) * viewOneRef.current.clientWidth
        },
        2: {
            ...prevState[2],
            left: (2 - activeView) * viewOneRef.current.clientWidth
        },
        3: {
            ...prevState[3],
            left: (3 - activeView) * viewOneRef.current.clientWidth
        }
    }))
}
```

`activeView` is the state variable that the `setActiveView()` function changes and `viewOneRef` is a reference to a div that's always rendered but may be hidden due to `overflow-hidden` (and has `absolute` position).

---

The **challenge I'm dealing with** is that clicking on any of the three buttons causes the `subviewStyle` dictionary to contain `left: NaN` values for all three children.

Confusingly, if I hardcode a value that gets called when `NewPaymentWidgetFooter` calls the `setActiveView` like below:

```
<NewPaymentWidgetFooter ref={footerRef} setActiveView={() => setActiveView(2)} />
```

then everything works fine and `subviewStyle` contains appropriate values for the `left` keys (e.g., `left: 424`).

Why does the dynamic option not work when hardcoding a parameter to pass back does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setActiveView` prop value you pass to `NewPaymentWidgetFooter` is `() => setActiveView()`, which will always call `setActiveView` without any parameters. If you pass it a function that calls `setActiveView` with its parameter, like this

```
<NewPaymentWidgetFooter ref={footerRef} setActiveView={(n) => setActiveView(n)}/>
```

it should use the value you pass to the callback.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed correct. Regards to your suggestion to specify type parameters, this is the first time I'm seeing such approach. Is there any drawback to letting react infer an `unknown` type?

Comment: You're welcome! Having the ref element unknown would not be a big deal, but if you don't specify the props type the inferred resulting component has no props. I don't even see how the code would type check as `props.setActiveView` won't exist, but I guess some code was left out.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it but I think you might be referring to something that's exclusive to TypeScript? As far as I know, ReactJS nor vanilla javascript don't typecheck. You'd only get an error at the time of executing the code, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Ah wait, I thought there was a `typescript` tag, but it's just `reactjs`, my bad! My comments were indeed TypeScript specific, I'll remove the last bit from the answer.